# Samsung S7 Edge cannot show png transparent background

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I had an Android app, in other Android device the `PNG` image transparent background can show other layer background under that `PNG` image, but in Samsung S7 Edge the `PNG` image transparent background is not transparent, the transparent shows gray and white lattice no showing the layer under it.

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you could post an image of the issue

Comment: Added image, please take a look, thanks.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your view that is displaying the `PNG`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: try to use `webView.clearCache(true);`
  `webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`
  `webView.getBackground().setAlpha(0);`
  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`
all are not work